# sudo "broken" - getting PAM error messages

Tags: raspbian-buster, sudo, pi-hole

I have a Raspberry Pi on my local network running Pi-hole. It's been all good for months, but suddenly I'm experiencing problems.

When I'm logged into the RPI with ssh and try to do anything `sudo` related I get these error messages:

```
$ echo hi
hi

$ sudo echo hi
sudo: unable to resolve host rpi3: Name or service not known
sudo: pam_open_session: Permission denied
sudo: policy plugin failed session initialization
```

I suspect the root cause to be related to the two later lines as I have not changed the hostname since the setup and `/etc/hosts` and `hostname` seems to be all good.

I got one other clue from `/var/log/auth.log` from around when the problems started (I believe this is just after a restart caused by a power outage):

```
Oct  2 18:17:18 rpi3 CRON[235]: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...required)pam_unix.so]
Oct  2 18:17:18 rpi3 CRON[235]: PAM (cron) no module name supplied
```

Just for the record. Here's the hosts:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     locqlhost ip6-locamhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodew
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1   rpi3
```

Hostname:

```
$ hostname
rpi3
```

Do you have any clues on what the real problem is here? And how to solve it?

(Please don't close this as a duplicate, because most related questions with similar error messages seem to be related people changing their hostname incorrectly)

#### Update with extra information

I'm running Raspberry Pi OS 10 (Buster) with kernel 5.4.51+.

I've redacted the username in the output below. *"Tillatelse avvist"* means *"Permission denied"*.

```
$ journalctl -b -e
[...]
Oct 03 11:09:02 rpi3 CRON[1019]: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...required)pam_unix.so]
Oct 03 11:09:02 rpi3 CRON[1019]: PAM (cron) no module name supplied
Oct 03 11:09:02 rpi3 cron[223]: Tillatelse avvist
Oct 03 11:09:02 rpi3 CRON[1019]: Tillatelse avvist
Oct 03 11:09:04 rpi3 systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Oct 03 11:09:05 rpi3 sessionclean[1024]: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xmlreader.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/xmlreader.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/xmlreader.so: undefined 
Oct 03 11:09:05 rpi3 sessionclean[1024]: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so: undefined symbol: dom_node_c
Oct 03 11:09:05 rpi3 sessionclean[1024]: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xmlreader.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/xmlreader.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/xmlreader.so: undefined 
Oct 03 11:09:05 rpi3 sessionclean[1024]: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so: undefined symbol: dom_node_c
Oct 03 11:09:05 rpi3 systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Oct 03 11:09:05 rpi3 systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Oct 03 11:10:01 rpi3 CRON[1067]: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...required)pam_unix.so]
Oct 03 11:10:01 rpi3 CRON[1067]: PAM (cron) no module name supplied
Oct 03 11:10:01 rpi3 cron[223]: Tillatelse avvist
Oct 03 11:10:01 rpi3 CRON[1067]: Tillatelse avvist
Oct 03 11:11:02 rpi3 sshd[1072]: Accepted publickey for [username] from 192.168.1.32 port 51912 ssh2: RSA SHA256:P/y5sNVdEePPLOfcoR7VMdBXbWbu6wrus3I7BhoyGGU
Oct 03 11:11:02 rpi3 sshd[1072]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user [username] by (uid=0)
Oct 03 11:11:02 rpi3 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 1001.
Oct 03 11:11:02 rpi3 systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/1001...
Oct 03 11:11:02 rpi3 systemd-logind[292]: New session c2 of user [username].
Oct 03 11:11:02 rpi3 systemd[1]: Started User Runtime Directory /run/user/1001.
Oct 03 11:11:02 rpi3 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1001...
Oct 03 11:11:02 rpi3 systemd[1077]: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...required)pam_unix.so]
Oct 03 11:11:02 rpi3 systemd[1077]: PAM (systemd-user) no module name supplied
Oct 03 11:11:02 rpi3 systemd[1077]: PAM failed: Permission denied
Oct 03 11:11:02 rpi3 systemd[1077]: user@1001.service: Failed to set up PAM session: Operation not permitted
Oct 03 11:11:02 rpi3 systemd[1077]: user@1001.service: Failed at step PAM spawning /lib/systemd/systemd: Operation not permitted
Oct 03 11:11:02 rpi3 systemd[1]: user@1001.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Oct 03 11:11:02 rpi3 systemd[1]: Failed to start User Manager for UID 1001.
Oct 03 11:11:03 rpi3 systemd[1]: Started Session c2 of user [username].
Oct 03 11:11:07 rpi3 sudo[1100]:    [username] : unable to resolve host rpi3
Oct 03 11:11:07 rpi3 sudo[1100]:    [username] : problem with defaults entries ; TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/[username] ; USER=root ;
Oct 03 11:11:07 rpi3 sudo[1100]: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...required)pam_unix.so]
Oct 03 11:11:07 rpi3 sudo[1100]: PAM (sudo) no module name supplied
Oct 03 11:11:07 rpi3 sudo[1100]:    [username] : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/[username] ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/echo hei
Oct 03 11:11:07 rpi3 sudo[1100]:    [username] : pam_open_session: Permission denied ; TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/[username] ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/echo hei
Oct 03 11:11:25 rpi3 dbus-daemon[261]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=1001 pid=1108 comm=
Oct 03 11:11:25 rpi3 systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Oct 03 11:11:26 rpi3 dbus-daemon[261]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Oct 03 11:11:26 rpi3 systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Oct 03 11:11:56 rpi3 systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
```

Comment: What is your operating system? Do you find something related in `journalctl -b -e`?

Comment: @ingo: Sorry for forgetting about the OS. :D It's Buster@5.4.51+. I've added the info you asked for.

Comment: "just after a restart caused by a power outage" probably a corrupted filesystem. You can try to repair this, **BUT** most of us would just restore from a backup.

Answer (score 3):

The update with the journal logging gives some more details but it is difficult to interpret it without having access to the system. My first idea is that there is a problem with `[...required)pam_unix.so]` that cannot be loaded the right way. `pam_unix.so` is an essential PAM module needed for classic unix authentication and local login using files `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/group`. All other error messages may be follow up errors.

The serious problem is that you cannot run `sudo` anymore and do not can modify system configuration files. But to check the situation you can run read only

```
rpi ~$ pam-auth-update
```

On my RasPi it looks:

```
--- snip ---
PAM profiles to enable
      [*] Unix authentication
      [*] Register user sessions in the systemd control group hierarchy
      [ ] Create home directory on login
      [*] Register check to see if default password has been changed when SSH is enabled
```

`Unix authentication` must be enabled. That is the PAM module `pam_unix.so`. For more details look at the files in `/etc/pam.d/` for the settings of `pam_unix.so`. Look at the `common-*` files first. Compare them with a running system. To modify the files you can try to run the RasPi in rescue- or emergency mode. For this just append one of the following targets to `/boot/cmdline.txt`. Try them in this order:

```
systemd.unit=rescue.target
systemd.unit=emergency.target
```

and boot the RasPi.

And yes, before doing all of this it is a good idea to take a backup of your system.